# Props in vue 3 typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I have a component like this, in the propы HEADER I pass the string.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="pb-5">

      <job-filters-sidebar-checkbox-group
        header="Job types"
        :uniqueValues="uniqueJobTypes"
        :mutation="ADD_SELECTED_JOB_TYPES"
      />

    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

In the child component I accept props and specify the type. But the typescript swears at the header in the child component.

```
<template>
  <accordion :header="header">
    
  </accordion>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Accordion from "@/components/Shared/Accordion.vue";
import { defineComponent, ref, PropType } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "JobFiltersSidebarChecbox",
  components: {
    Accordion,
  },
  props: {
    header: {
      type: String as PropType<string>,
      require: true,
    },
    uniqueValues: {
      type: Set as PropType<Set<string>>,
      required: true,
    },
    mutation: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {...},
});
</script>
```

Comment: It seems you have a typo, change `require` to `required` in the `header` prop definition.

Comment: "swears" - this is not a clear problem statement at all. If there's error message, please, post it

Answer (score 0):

**change require to required**  in the header prop definition